# How to run Android ICS on a PC (win7) inside a VM?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, virtualization

I have a PC and would like for kids to run Android games/edu apps. I have a touchscreen. How hard is it to run ICS inside a VM (VirtualBox or any other VM platform (MS, VMware)

There are answers about older versions of android. but I would like to run ICS.

Comment: Have you considered blue stacks, which could run Android apps in Windows PC?

Comment: And if you insist on a VM: There always is the [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), which includes an Emulator.

Comment: The SDK's own Emulator is slow in its own right - translating from ARM<->x86 etc, might be better to use [Android x86](http://www.android-x86.org/) ;)

Answer (score 1):

- Recent versions of the SDK include a native x86 Android image. (http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html)
- http://android-x86.org offers a 4.0 image that can be run from VirtualBox.
- http://androvm.org/blog/ offers a Jellybean (4.1) image for VirtualBox.

Note that performance may not be so great.

Answer (score 0):

Something that may be easier to install is [Bluestacks](http://bluestacks.com/). I think it should meet your needs.

Edit: Well... except it is not ICS :P I would then go to SDK emulators...

Comment: bluestacks has a bug and does not register touches on my touchscreen monitor.